# SQL join table to selected records

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

Example:

```
SELECT SUM(SALARY) FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id > 10) a LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.person = b.person
```

I want join table2 records only to `(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id > 10)` records, my example is not correct.

`table1` contain 100mln records and I cant join `table2` to all records I must use subquery

Comment: which table is the `salary` column in?

Comment: @TomMac it's onlny example I neet have `salary_type` FROM table2 and add condition to count only some aslary types.

Comment: (1) Why is your example not correct?  (2) Why can't you use `table2` to all records?  (3) Why do you have to use a subquery?

Comment: Because I have so many records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming, you salary is not summing up correctly (you are getting more than you expect). This is because `LEFT JOIN` will leave NULL for the rowsthat doesn't have match in `b`.
For this SQL:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM   (select * from (SELECT 123   AS Salary,
               'Tom' AS person
        UNION
        SELECT 343   AS Salary,
               'Bob' AS person
        UNION
        SELECT 877   AS Salary,
               'Tom' AS person) as t where t.Salary > 123) a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                  FROM   (SELECT 'Tom' AS person,
                                 1     AS id
                          UNION
                          SELECT 'Bob' AS person,
                                 2     AS id) AS t
                  WHERE  t.id = 1) AS b
              ON a.person = b.person
```

you will have this output:

[image: sql]

So `INNER JOIN` should work for you.

```
SELECT SUM(SALARY) FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id > 10) a
LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.person = b.person
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will get you going in the correct direction....

```
select sum(a.salary)
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.person = b.person and b.salary_type = "something"
where a.id > 10
;
```